# make: *** No rule to make target `Arguments.o', needed by `all'. Stop

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I made a simple makefile, here its content:

```
# Just get cpp files in source folder, and remove ./source/ prefix
SOURCES=$(subst $(SOURCE_PATH)/,,$(shell find $(SOURCE_PATH) -name "*.cpp"))
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

OUTPUT_NAME=slang

STD=c++14

all: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(SOURCES) -o$(OUTPUT_PATH)$(OUTPUT_NAME)
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c -std=$(STD) -I$(INCLUDE_PATH) -L$(LIBRARY_PATH) -o$(TEMP_PATH)$@ $(SOURCE_PATH)$<
```

There are also some folders, but they are just constants for folders.
But when I run make, I see an error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `Arguments.o', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

So I'd like to ask a solution for this problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Make doesn't know where to find `Arguments.cpp`. Are there subdirectories in `src/`?

Comment: No, its path is ./src/Arguments.cpp

Comment: `%.o: %.cpp` -> `%.o: $(SOURCE_PATH)/%.cpp`. You could also use `vpath`.

Comment: Now everything works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `vpath` directive to specify where to find the sources.

```
vpath %.cpp $(SOURCE_PATH)
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
```